# Unpected behaviour while calling boto3 library to put an object in S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, mailgun

I am receiving the following log almost everytime when I try to upload a file on S3

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.mailgun.net:443 "POST /v3/delivery.exportify.in/messages HTTP/1.1" 200 96
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)                                               
Done                                                           
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f4772584c10>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7f4772526950>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function lazy_call.<locals>._handler at 0x7f476a701c60>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f4772526710>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
DEBUG:botocore.client:Registering retry handlers for service: s3
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f4772584c10>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7f4772526950>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function lazy_call.<locals>._handler at 0x7f476a701c60>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f4772526710>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
DEBUG:botocore.client:Registering retry handlers for service: s3
DEBUG:boto3.resources.factory:Loading s3:s3
DEBUG:s3transfer.utils:Acquiring 0
DEBUG:s3transfer.tasks:UploadSubmissionTask(transfer_id=0, {'transfer_future': <s3transfer.futures.TransferFuture object at 0x7f47682d2380>}) about to wait for the following futures []
DEBUG:s3transfer.tasks:UploadSubmissionTask(transfer_id=0, {'transfer_future': <s3transfer.futures.TransferFuture object at 0x7f47682d2380>}) done waiting for dependent futures
DEBUG:s3transfer.tasks:Executing task UploadSubmissionTask(transfer_id=0, {'transfer_future': <s3transfer.futures.TransferFuture object at 0x7f47682d2380>}) with kwargs {'client': <botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7f472abcfbb0>, 'config': <boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig object at 0x7f47682648b0>, 'osutil': <s3transfer.utils.OSUtils object at 0x7f4768264940>, 'request_executor': <s3transfer.futures.BoundedExecutor object at 0x7f4768264b50>, 'transfer_future': <s3transfer.futures.TransferFuture object at 0x7f47682d2380>}
DEBUG:s3transfer.futures:Submitting task PutObjectTask(transfer_id=0, {'bucket': 'bucket-name', 'key': 'testing_sample/document_upload.pdf', 'extra_args': {}}) to executor <s3transfer.futures.BoundedExecutor object at 0x7f4768264b50> for transfer request: 0.
DEBUG:s3transfer.utils:Acquiring 0
DEBUG:s3transfer.tasks:PutObjectTask(transfer_id=0, {'bucket': 'bucket-name', 'key': 'testing_sample/document_upload.pdf', 'extra_args': {}}) about to wait for the following futures []
DEBUG:s3transfer.utils:Releasing acquire 0/None
DEBUG:s3transfer.tasks:PutObjectTask(transfer_id=0, {'bucket': 'bucket-name', 'key': 'testing_sample/document_upload.pdf', 'extra_args': {}}) done waiting for dependent futures
DEBUG:s3transfer.tasks:Executing task PutObjectTask(transfer_id=0, {'bucket': 'bucket-name', 'key': 'testing_sample/document_upload.pdf', 'extra_args': {}}) with kwargs {'client': <botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7f472abcfbb0>, 'fileobj': <s3transfer.utils.ReadFileChunk object at 0x7f47682d2980>, 'bucket': 'bucket-name', 'key': 'testing_sample/document_upload.pdf', 'extra_args': {}}
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function validate_ascii_metadata at 0x7f4772587400>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function sse_md5 at 0x7f4772586830>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function convert_body_to_file_like_object at 0x7f4772587d00>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7f47725867a0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_cache of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3ArnParamHandler.handle_arn of <botocore.utils.S3ArnParamHandler object at 0x7f47682647c0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f47725865f0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function conditionally_calculate_md5 at 0x7f47727f9e10>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function add_expect_header at 0x7f4772586b00>
DEBUG:botocore.handlers:Adding expect 100 continue header to request.
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.set_request_url of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f4772587e20>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Making request for OperationModel(name=PutObject) with params: {'url_path': '/bucket-name/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'PUT', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.20.24 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.13.0-1019-aws Botocore/1.23.46', 'Content-MD5': 'am8sGp8eMgSJANnj7o/9eg==', 'Expect': '100-continue'}, 'body': <s3transfer.utils.ReadFileChunk object at 0x7f47682d2980>, 'url': 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-south-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f472abcfd30>, 'has_streaming_input': True, 'auth_type': None, 'signing': {'bucket': 'bucket-name'}}}
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function signal_not_transferring at 0x7f477186eb00>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f472abcfca0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-signer.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_signer of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7f47682648e0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-signer.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f47725864d0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-sign.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_endpoint of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7f47682648e0>>
DEBUG:botocore.utils:Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
DEBUG:botocore.utils:Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf
DEBUG:botocore.utils:URI updated to: https://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Calculating signature using v4 auth.
DEBUG:botocore.auth:CanonicalRequest:
PUT
/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf

content-md5:am8sGp8eMgSJANnj7o/9eg==
host:bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20230316T060727Z

content-md5;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
DEBUG:botocore.auth:StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230316T060727Z
20230316/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request
73df0e57bb35789f93cdaeef5cf0e5131c92e2c527356c6602e972cd29d5b748
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Signature:
2642d30b4a3287cf3b47c897c35d882ed2a8e243d006ae9d5cc7e32160cb1027
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function signal_transferring at 0x7f477186eb90>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=PUT, url=https://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf, headers={'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.20.24 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.13.0-1019-aws Botocore/1.23.46', 'Content-MD5': b'am8sGp8eMgSJANnj7o/9eg==', 'Expect': b'100-continue', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20230316T060727Z', 'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': b'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIASJ6IEVCR5YAOGHO3/20230316/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-md5;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=2642d30b4a3287cf3b47c897c35d882ed2a8e243d006ae9d5cc7e32160cb1027', 'Content-Length': '434902'}>
DEBUG:botocore.httpsession:Certificate path: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443
DEBUG:botocore.awsrequest:Waiting for 100 Continue response.
DEBUG:botocore.awsrequest:100 Continue response seen, now sending request body.
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443 "PUT /testing_sample/document_upload.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 0
DEBUG:botocore.parsers:Response headers: {'x-amz-id-2': '6/Ce0cUqagsX1JXb+qlySLESCWag6fibJjra5hGgYIqZRr4m+wG4mIY6JLNWLGMVeRUtCu9bZuA=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'Q4EY6E30DNM40PZE', 'Date': 'Thu, 16 Mar 2023 06:07:28 GMT', 'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 'ETag': '"6a6f2c1a9f1e32048900d9e3ee8ffd7a"', 'Server': 'AmazonS3', 'Content-Length': '0'}
DEBUG:botocore.parsers:Response body:
b''
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f4768264730>
DEBUG:botocore.retryhandler:No retry needed.
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:s3transfer.utils:Releasing acquire 0/None
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7f47725867a0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_cache of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <bound method S3ArnParamHandler.handle_arn of <botocore.utils.S3ArnParamHandler object at 0x7f47682647c0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f47725865f0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <function add_expect_header at 0x7f4772586b00>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.set_request_url of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f4772587e20>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Making request for OperationModel(name=PutObjectAcl) with params: {'url_path': '/bucket-name/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf?acl', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'PUT', 'headers': {'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', 'Content-MD5': '1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==', 'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.20.24 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.13.0-1019-aws Botocore/1.23.46'}, 'body': b'', 'url': 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf?acl', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-south-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f472abcfd30>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None, 'signing': {'bucket': 'bucket-name'}}}
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <function signal_not_transferring at 0x7f477186eb00>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f472abcfca0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-signer.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_signer of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7f47682648e0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-signer.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f47725864d0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-sign.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_endpoint of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7f47682648e0>>
DEBUG:botocore.utils:Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf?acl
DEBUG:botocore.utils:URI updated to: https://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf?acl
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Calculating signature using v4 auth.
DEBUG:botocore.auth:CanonicalRequest:
PUT
/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf
acl=
content-md5:1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
host:bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-acl:public-read
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20230316T060727Z

content-md5;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
DEBUG:botocore.auth:StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230316T060727Z
20230316/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request
d93f09f663b61775d4895d2f5795272621917ffa1a180b6eead47109060a556a
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Signature:
41efbf01a31e536cdd7c52d788645853f42480d87f715b4ac8471604b42b409a
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <function signal_transferring at 0x7f477186eb90>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=PUT, url=https://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testing_sample/document_upload.pdf?acl, headers={'x-amz-acl': b'public-read', 'Content-MD5': b'1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==', 'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.20.24 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.13.0-1019-aws Botocore/1.23.46', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20230316T060727Z', 'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIASJ6IEVCR5YAOGHO3/20230316/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-md5;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=41efbf01a31e536cdd7c52d788645853f42480d87f715b4ac8471604b42b409a', 'Content-Length': '0'}>
DEBUG:botocore.httpsession:Certificate path: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443 "PUT /testing_sample/document_upload.pdf?acl HTTP/1.1" 200 0
DEBUG:botocore.parsers:Response headers: {'x-amz-id-2': '8hi1xncKZ+zBW4NtRyimljdeqHL9sVlUUbPYSUw2T+tgJ+BzuQ4uMDojUXLoQzxHHNkff85zVM0=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'Q4EWABM7Z9AW934D', 'Date': 'Thu, 16 Mar 2023 06:07:28 GMT', 'Server': 'AmazonS3', 'Content-Length': '0'}
DEBUG:botocore.parsers:Response body:
b''
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event needs-retry.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f4768264730>
DEBUG:botocore.retryhandler:No retry needed.
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event needs-retry.s3.PutObjectAcl: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7f47725867a0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_cache of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <bound method S3ArnParamHandler.handle_arn of <botocore.utils.S3ArnParamHandler object at 0x7f47682647c0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f47725865f0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function add_expect_header at 0x7f4772586b00>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.set_request_url of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-call.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f4772587e20>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Making request for OperationModel(name=GetBucketLocation) with params: {'url_path': '/bucket-name?location', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'GET', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.20.24 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.13.0-1019-aws Botocore/1.23.46'}, 'body': b'', 'url': 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name?location', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-south-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f472abcfd30>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None, 'signing': {'bucket': 'bucket-name'}}}
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function signal_not_transferring at 0x7f477186eb00>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f472abcfca0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-signer.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_signer of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7f47682648e0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event choose-signer.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f47725864d0>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event before-sign.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_endpoint of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7f47682648e0>>
DEBUG:botocore.utils:Request is GetBucketLocation operation, not checking for DNS compatibility.
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Calculating signature using v4 auth.
DEBUG:botocore.auth:CanonicalRequest:
GET
/bucket-name
location=
host:s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20230316T060727Z

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
DEBUG:botocore.auth:StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230316T060727Z
20230316/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request
68d0cf08f558ba70e563d6558c2a4009cd6c949a5170bef336999d12620f7405
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Signature:
5644f5378699d18653d79331e3cc264ae4b686ce7ee49d3166fb04b899c4b29b
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function signal_transferring at 0x7f477186eb90>
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=GET, url=https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name?location, headers={'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.20.24 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.13.0-1019-aws Botocore/1.23.46', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20230316T060727Z', 'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIASJ6IEVCR5YAOGHO3/20230316/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=5644f5378699d18653d79331e3cc264ae4b686ce7ee49d3166fb04b899c4b29b'}>
DEBUG:botocore.httpsession:Certificate path: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /bucket-name?location HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:botocore.parsers:Response headers: {'x-amz-id-2': 'DsPVu8lO7ibF5gLWEgtwi9M5ljn24oxZNZX655SqPlky10XMSli8gANEiV72bXrfwDRFM0v6a3A=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'Q4EKAXQ2RFC1WY7A', 'Date': 'Thu, 16 Mar 2023 06:07:28 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Server': 'AmazonS3'}
DEBUG:botocore.parsers:Response body:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<LocationConstraint xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">ap-south-1</LocationConstraint>'
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event needs-retry.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f4768264730>
DEBUG:botocore.retryhandler:No retry needed.
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event needs-retry.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f47682647f0>>
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event after-call.s3.GetBucketLocation: calling handler <function parse_get_bucket_location at 0x7f4772587250>
```

Has anyone encountered such warning or error before?
This specific log is occuring multiple times in my system logs and I assume that because of this thing my files are not being attached in my mailgun emails and this is resulting in emails not being delivered to recipients from the system. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something seems to be in Debug mode. Please show us your code that is uploading the object to S3.

Comment: Is it successfully uploading? Are you saying that it isn't uploading, or are you just unhappy with the information in the log file?

Comment: It is uploading the file in S3 @JohnRotenstein

Comment: So your only concern is the contents of the log file? Where is the log appearing?

Comment: Yes, my concern is only this particular log appearing multiple times in my logs due to which I may miss out on some other crucial logs that I want to track

Comment: Is there any particular message that is worrying you? Somehow you have managed to turn on DEBUG-level messages, so there is a lot of information you should simply ignore unless there is an issue you are wanting to solve. Did you use `boto3.set_stream_logger()` in your code? See: [Boto3 reference — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html)

Comment: Yes, I have turned on DEBUG in my Dockerfile. Is this log coming because of that?
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5001 wsgi:app --access-logfile '-' --timeout 600 --log-level debug

Comment: No idea, but _something_ is making it output all that!

Comment: Is it because of the difference in the versions of these libraries that are installed in my docker containers v/s the versions of these libraries that are usually required to perform these operations.